# Remove duplicates appearing next to each other, but keep it if it appears again later

Tags: matlab, duplicates

I have a vector that could look like this:

`v = [1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 2 1 1 1];`

that is, the number of equal elements can vary, but they always increase and decrease stepwise by 1.

What I want is an easy way to be left with a new vector looking like this:

`v2 = [ 1 2 3 2 1];`

holding all the different elements (in the right order as they appear in `v`), but only one of each. Preferably without looping, since generally my vectors are about 10 000 elements long, and already inside a loop that's taking for ever to run.

Thank you so much for any answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) for this. All you're really asking for is: Delete any element that's equal to the one in front of it.

`diff` return the difference between all adjacent elements in a vector. If there is no difference, it will return `0`. `v(ind~=0)` will give you all elements that have a value different than zero. The `1` in the beginning is to make sure the first element is counted. As `diff` returns the difference between elements, `numel(diff(v)) = numel(v)-1`.

```
v = [1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 2 1 1 1];
ind = [1 diff(v)];
v(ind~=0)
ans =
     1     2     3     2     1
```

This can of course be done in a single line if you want:

```
v([1, diff(v)]~=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `diff` which, for a vector `X`, returns `[X(2)-X(1)  X(3)-X(2) ... X(n)-X(n-1)]` (type `help diff` for details on this function).  Since the elements in your vector always increase or decrease by 1, then

```
diff(v)
```

will be a vector (of size one less than `v`) with zeros and ones where a one indicates a step up or down.  We can ignore all the zeros as they imply repeated numbers.  We can convert this to a logical array as

```
logical(diff(v))
```

so that we can index into `v` and access its elements as

```
v(logical(diff(v)))
```

which returns

```
1     2     3     2
```

This is almost what you want, just without the final number which can be added as

```
[v(logical(diff(v))) v(end)]
```

Try the above and see what happens!