# Remove consecutive duplicated values but leave it if it appears later in R

Tags: r

I have a vector that could look like this:

```
t <- c(2,2,3,3,3,2,2,3,4,2,2,2,3,3,10,10,10,1,10,10)
```

What I want is an easy way to be left with a new vector looking like this:

```
t2 <- c(2,3,2,3,4,2,3,10,1,10)
```

holding all the different elements (in the right order as they appear in t), but only one of each. Preferably without looping, since generally my vectors are about 6 000 000 elements long

I found a similar problem and solution for Matlab but I can't implement it in R and also there was a pattern in the increase and decrease between numbers, which is not the case in my case

[Remove duplicates appearing next to each other, but keep it if it appears again later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24327771/remove-duplicates-appearing-next-to-each-other-but-keep-it-if-it-appears-again)

Answer (score 4):

This is just the `values` from the `rle` function:

```
> rle(t)$values
 [1]  2  3  2  3  4  2  3 10  1 10
```

The full output includes the counts of each repeat. We just get the `values` component here.

Or you could use the same algorithm as the Matlab code references, which looks like this:

```
> t[c(1,diff(t))!=0]
 [1]  2  3  2  3  4  2  3 10  1 10
```